# XML/XSL Table won't populate

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to create a shopping basket with XML/XSL and Javascript for a university assignment.  I have created a stock list with XML/XSL but when I run the code in a browser the table shows but is not populated.  I think it is a problem with my xpath but I am unsure of how to fix it.

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="basket.xsl"?>
<data-set>
<basket id="001">
<Product>Shorts (F) </Product>
<Description>Stone Wash Denim Shorts</Description>
<stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
<price>£25.90</price>
</basket>
<basket id="002">
<Product>Bag (F)</Product>
<Description>Leather Shoulder Bag</Description>
<stockLevel>4</stockLevel>
<price>£50.45</price>
</basket>
<basket id="003">
<Product>Blouse (F)</Product>
<Description>Vintage Blue Silk Polka Dot Blouse</Description>
<stockLevel>8</stockLevel>
<price>£45.99</price>
</basket>
<basket id="004">
<Product>Boots (F)</Product>
<Description>Soft Leather Brown Ankle Boots</Description>
<stockLevel>3</stockLevel>
<price>£65.35</price>
</basket>
<basket id="005">
<Product>Belts (F)</Product>
<Description>Woven Finish Fashion Belt</Description>
<stockLevel>15</stockLevel>
<price>£21.99</price>
</basket>
<basket id="006">
<Product>Shirt (M)</Product>
<Description>Jacquard Pattern Wrangler Western Shirt</Description>
<stockLevel>19</stockLevel>
<price>£34.87</price>
</basket>
<basket id="007">
<Product>Shoes (M) </Product>
<Description>Suede Ankle Boots</Description>
<stockLevel>6</stockLevel>
<price>£55.00</price>
</basket>
<basket id="008">
<Product>Trousers (M)</Product>
<Description>Izod Peach Chinos</Description>
<stockLevel>23</stockLevel>
<price>£31/75</price>
</basket>
<basket id="009">
<Product>Belt (M)</Product>
<Description>Suede Casual Belt</Description>
<stockLevel>4</stockLevel>
<price>£22.98</price>
</basket>
<basket id="010">
<Product>Hat (M)</Product>
<Description>Trilby Style Brown Woven Fix</Description>
<stockLevel>2</stockLevel>
<price>£67.80</price>
</basket>
</data-set>
```

and my XSL code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method = "html" omit-xml-declaration = "no" doctype-system = "http://www.w3.org.TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />

<xsl:template match = "/">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> My Shopping Basket </title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" bgcolor="White">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Item Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<xsl:for-each select="basket">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Product" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="stockLevel" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="price" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What this code produces is a blank table.  It has all the headings and columns (Item Name

Item Description

Price

Quantity)

but no data is populated into it.

Comment: You'll get more response here if you post error messages and maybe what the resulting HTML looks like.  Don't make us run your transformation to see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template matches `/`, whereas your root element is `/data-set`

Either:

- change your template to element `<xsl:template match = "/data-set">`
- Or create an additional template `<xsl:template match = "data-set">` and then call `<xsl:apply-templates select='data-set'>` from the existing `<xsl:template match = "/">` template.

As an aside, you can also consider refactoring the `basket` mapping out of a for-each and into its own template, which is then called via `apply-templates`. This allows the same benefits that refactoring allows in other languages, e.g. allows you to reuse this template.

Comment: I changed the template element to     <xsl:template match = "/data-set"> however it still produces a blank table.

Comment: Never mind I was being really stupid.  Thank you for the help.  I was trying to open the wrong file.

Comment: Great :) Here's an example of the refactoring into call templates I was mentioning above : [fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yo/4)